# React Native - run script from cdn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cdn

Is there a way to run a script from a cdn in react-native?

For example in ReactJS:

```
 //index.html
 <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://js.xendit.co/v1/xendit.min.js"
 ></script>

 //react component file
 const Xendit = window.Xendit;
 const Component = ({card_number}) => {
     const[cardNumberValidated, setCardNumberValidated] = useState(false);
     useEffect(() => {
        const isValidated = Xendit.card.validate(card_number);
        setCardNumberValidated(isValidated)
     },[])
     ...
 }
```

I tried downloading the file and saving it locally, but it doesn't work

```
saved file
Xendit.min.js

//import
import Xendit from '@myUtils/Xendit.min';
import {KEY} from '@myUtils/XenditUtils';

//call it
Xendit.setPublishableKey(KEY)
//it returns Xendit.default.setPublishableKey is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xendit-js-node`

```
...
import Xendit from 'xendit-js-node';
...
Xendit.setPublishableKey('xnd_public_development_OYqIfOUth+GowsY6LeJOHzLCZtSj84J9kXDn+Rxj/mbf/LCoCQdxgA==');
...
Xendit.card.createAuthentication(threeDSData, this._tokenResponseHandler);
...
//etc.
```

There is an official example React Native app: https://github.com/xendit/xendit-react-example

Comment: Thanks! I was hesitant on whether I should use this or not since I was not sure if this was the official example because I couldn't find it in their documentation, but I implemented it still. 

Also, I guess there is no way to run scripts from a CDN in react native?